# How to select the middle value (Median) from a list of any number of expressions

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a query in PostgreSQL, wherein I need to select the middle value of the 3 timestamps that I am passing. I know there is Least and the greatest function available in PostgreSQL, that allows me to choose the least and the greatest number respectively.

But in my problem statement I need to select the middle value and want to know the easy and effective way to do so?

Query:

```
select 
    scvt.vc_id, 
    least(start_time1,start_time2,start_time3) as "actual_class_start_time", -- <- the middle value of start times
from ...
```

I need to select the middle value in the highlighted text, is there an effective way?

Comment: Please simplify and minimize your code to the most relevant parts.

Comment: The line in which I am trying to find the mid value is.
- **least(start_time1,start_time2,start_time3)** as "actual_class_start_time"

Comment: @S-Man Have done so

Answer (score 1):

If it's exactly three values every time, you can do a custom function that picks the middle of the three:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION middleval(anyelement, anyelement, anyelement)
   RETURNS date AS
$$
  SELECT d
  FROM (VALUES ($1), ($2), ($3)) AS t (d)
  order by 1
  offset 1
  limit 1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;
```

Then your code would read:

```
select scvt.vc_id, middleval (start_time1, start_time2, start_time3)
```